# Steps to install perl version 5.26.3 in Solaris 11 Host

Tags: perl, solaris

I would like to install perl version 5.26.3 in host running with Solaris 11 using service account. The installation has to be done in Application file system or in user directory.

Please could someone share with the steps to install ?

Please note that perl 5.26 version is already installed at OS level , but we want to have our own perl installation in application folder rather than using OS level perl interpreter

Thanks.

Comment: There's an `INSTALL` file in the root of the tarball. Alternatively, you could use `perlbrew`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of installing from source using the defaults. If you want to modify the defaults, have a look at the [INSTALL](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.28.3/INSTALL) document.

```
$ wget https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.26.3.tar.bz2
$ bunzip2 perl-5.26.3.tar.bz2
$ tar xvf perl-5.26.3.tar
$ cd perl-5.26.3
$ sh Configure -de -Dprefix='/some/dir' # Where to install
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

Then edit the PATH environment variable to include `/some/dir/bin` such that the shell can find the new perl.